# 'NoneType' object is not iterable - array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the `result_first_round` array. I want to move `result_first_round` to `first_temp` by using `res.get()`, but when I print `res.get()`, it shows is none. Is there anyway to use `res.get()`?

result_first_round is array.

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=int(args.process))
for i in range(int(args.process)):
    result_first_round.append(pool.apply_async(Son_Algorithm, (i,)))
pool.close()
pool.join()
first_temp = []
for res in result_first_round: 
    print(res.get())
    first_temp.append(res.get())
```

Comment: Have you tried res instead of res.get()?

Comment: What is your actual problem?  The post title `NoneType object is not iterable` does not match the request of `res.get()` being none.